# Extjs 6/7 tree get right click event

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extreact, extjs7

I have this tree in ExtJs/ExtReact and I need the old `contextMenu` functionality which is nowhere to be found in these new versions so I decided to implement it. If you look at the demo you can see there is an event being fired (the node gets darker) when a right click is done on a node. I need to catch that event and create a custom context menu but the problem is that I can't find the event name anywhere in the [events list](https://docs.sencha.com/extreact/7.0.0/modern/Ext.grid.Tree.html#events).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `itemcontextmenu` event:

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/31va)